# Query log equivalent for Progress/OpenEdge

Tags: progress-4gl

Short story: A report running against a Progress database (OpenEdge Release 10.1C03) takes hours to complete. I suspect that it does not take advantage of existing data indexes. Would like to understand how it scans the data to then try to add an index that will make it run faster.

Source code of the report is not available. The code is native Progress 4GL, not SQL.

If it were an SQL database I would try to do a dump of SQL queries and would then go from that. With 4GL I did not find any such functionality. Is it possible to somehow peek at what gets executed at the low level?

What else can be done if there is no source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

If I recall correctly 10.1C should have the _usertablestat and _userindexstat virtual system tables available.  These allow you to observe, at runtime, what tables and indexes are being accessed by a particular session.  You can either write your own 4GL program to query them or you can use the screens in PROMON, R&D, 3 "Other Displays", 5 "I/O Operations by User by Table" and 6 "I/O Operations by User by Index".  That will show you what tables and indexes are actually in use and how much use they are getting.  If the observed data seems wrong it will probably give you a clue.  (If the VSTs are missing it might be because the db was upgraded from an older version -- add them with proutil dbname -C updatevsts.)

You could also use the session startup parameters -clientlog "filename" and -logentrytypes QryInfo to obtain more detailed information about the queries being executed.

Keep in mind that Progress is not SQL.  Unlike most SQL databases the 4gl uses a static, compile-time, optimizer.  Index selection happens when the code is compiled.  So unless you can recompile (and you seem to not have source so that seems unlikely) you won't be able to improve things by adding missing indexes.  You might, however, at least be able to show the person who does have source where the problem is.

Another tool that can help is the profiler.  This will identify where in the code the time is being spent.  That can also be good information to provide to the original vendor if they need help finding the problem.  For more information on the profiler: http://dbappraise.com/ppt/profiler.pptx

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

I did not know that indexes for a query get assigned when compiling. We do have .r files and we recompile the code from them (with some of our own customizations). Is compiling from .r going to reassign an index if add a new one?

Comment: A .r is the end result of compiling.  Source is usually a .p or a .w.  If you are able to compile you can also use the XREF option to get a listing that will show index selection.

Comment: Perhaps you have encrypted source?  Is this a vendor provided app?  If so which one?

Comment: yes, it is a vendor app, Infor SX.e
You are correct about it being an encrypted source. I don't know what came over me -- we have encrypted .p's of course.
I will try to research about Xref compilation option, thanks for the hint!

Comment: SX.e is usually distributed with encrypted source.  So, yes, you could recompile and maybe get it to pick up a new index.  You might also be able to get a look at the source -- some customers have access to a portal that will allow selected code to be reviewed.  You could also maybe use that just to help them understand where the query is going wrong and get it fixed.

Comment: Since I got you on the line... I tried querying _usertablestat and _userindexstat yesterday. The table stats show heavy usage on the table that I expected (in tens of millions of requests). But index stat shows zeros. Is that really because no index is being used, or is it because of these VST not being updated? I thought since _usertablestat has data, then index stat should have data too. Right?